# When does expand need to be used when mapping a <cword> command in vim?

Tags: vim

I can create a mapping that will search for the word under the cursor like so:

```
noremap <leader>/ :grep <cword> **<cr>
```

Why is it that unite mappings like unite (I doubt this is a unite specific issue) requires `<C-r>=expand('<cword>')<CR>` or `<c-r><c-w>` instead of `<cword>`?

```
nnoremap g/ :Unite -input=<C-r>=expand('<cword>')<CR> tag<CR>
```

Comment: Try without `expand()`.

Comment: Did not work in the later case only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special characters like `%` and `<cword>` are explained under `:help cmdline-special`.

> In Ex commands, at places where a file name can be used, the following
>   characters have a special meaning.  These can also be used in the expression
>   function `expand()`.

That explains why `:edit <cword>` works, but `:echo "<cword>"` does not: the latter does not take a file name. `:grep` just fuzzily refers to `[arguments]`, but naturally some of them have to be files. The `:Unite` command is universal (and custom), so you need to use `expand()` there. When in doubt, just try it out :-)

Comment: fzf.vim as a command Ag that doesn't take a file as an argument and I can use `<cword>` without `expand` in that case too.  The command definition doesn't specify `-complete=file` either.

Comment: The command may do a `expand()` on the passed argument(s) internally. Have you checked its implementation?

Comment: I found that Ag in fzf.vim eventually gets translated into a command run with `execute 'silent ! ... <cword>`.  If I run `:!echo <cword>` cword is translated into the word under the cursor even though vim has no idea if echo is looking for a file name (which it isn't).